# "Delete Form" within Index view

Tags: php, symfony, twig

## **Question**:

How can I render a 'DeleteForm' in inside my 'Index' view by using {{ form(deleteForms) }}

## Description:

I have followed the steps described in [**this**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18844591/2221407) SO answer, however I would like to streamline it a little more.

What is described there is to add the following to your indexAction:

```
//ProductController.php
//...

$deleteForms = array();

foreach ($entities as $entity) {
$deleteForms[$entity->getId()] = $this->createDeleteForm($entity->getId())->createView();
}
return $this->render('AppBundle:Product:index.html.twig', array(
'entities' => $entities,
'deleteForms' => $deleteForms,
));
```

And in your view add the following:
    {% for entity in entities %}
    //...
    
        
        {{ form_widget(deleteForms[entity.id]) }}
        
            
            {{ 'links.admin.form.delete' | trans({}, 'FooBundle') }}
        
    
    ...//
    {% endfor %}

Which works fine, my niggle is why render the form manually when anywhere (Update/Show etc) else I just do this:

```
{% for entity in entities %}
//...
{{ form(deleteForms) }}
...//
{% endfor %}
```

So I tried this instead but it resulted in this error:

> An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template
>   ("Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 1 passed to
>   Symfony\Component\Form\FormRenderer::renderBlock() must be an instance
>   of Symfony\Component\Form\FormView, array given, called in
>   C:\MyBundle\app\cache\dev\twig\f6\75\ae2ae7bebde1f4083ba543a1680ecdb4b1c359141e57ac01862c94660f2e.php
>   on line 176 and defined") in AppBundle:Product:index.html.twig at line
>   49.

I've Googled the error which suggests I need to be calling "->createView()" but this is already being called in the foreach array. I tried doing it in the Return section anyway as so:

```
return $this->render('AppBundle:Product:index.html.twig', array(
            'entities' => $entities,
            'deleteForms' => $deleteForms->createView(),
));
```

All this does is cause another error:

> Error: Call to a member function createView() on a non-object

So now I'm completely lost.
Any pointers in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seem to be creating an array of the "deleteForms" with the entity id as the key so when you call them in the template you should use that same format.

For example..

```
{% for entity in entities %}
    //...
    {{ form(deleteForms[entity.id]) }}
    ...//
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: I cannot believe after all that searching all I was missing is that. Thank-you **so so** much.